# Optimization of Oracle Text Name Search Facility on 11g R2

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-text

I'm trying to figure out how to get reasonable performance using the Oracle Text Name Search Facility on 11g R2.

For testing I have created a table with an objectid and fullname, populated from an existing table with approx. 5,400,000 rows:

```
create table personname as
select p.objectid, p.fname||chr(32)||p.mname||chr(32)||p.lname as fullname
from person p;
```

Then I setup the preferences for datastore and section group as follows:

```
begin
  begin
    ctx_ddl.create_preference('namesearch_ds', 'multi_column_datastore');
    ctx_ddl.set_attribute('namesearch_ds', 'columns', 'fullname');
  end;

  begin
    ctx_ddl.create_section_group('namesearch_sg', 'basic_section_group');
    ctx_ddl.add_ndata_section('namesearch_sg', 'fullname', 'fullname');
  end;
end;
```

And finally create the context index:

```
create index personname_idx
on personname(fullname)
indextype is ctxsys.context
parameters
('datastore namesearch_ds section group namesearch_sg sync(on commit)');
```

So far, all good.
However, querying is pretty slow. Doing a select like this:

```
select score(1), pn.* 
from personname pn
where contains(pn.fullname, 'ndata(fullname, Bjørn Egil Hansen)', 1) > 0
  and rownum <= 50
order by score(1) desc;
```

can take minutes, and response time seems to increase with the number of names in the query.

I have tried using various query hints as suggested by the Oracle doc, i.e.:

- FIRST_ROWS(50)
- DOMAIN_INDEX_SORT
- PARALLEL(8)

But it doesn't seem to make much difference (really hard to measure, though, since doing the same query a second time performs much faster).